# Parallel target search and serial blank search

Tags: vision

[Wolfe (1991)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/004269899290190T) reports an example of a search that seems to be parallel for target trials and serial for blank trials:
[image: From Wolfe, J. M. (1992). “Effortless” texture segmentation and “parallel” visual search are not the same thing. Vision Research, 32(4), 757-763.]

Here's another example from [Wang et al., 1994](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/BF03206946)
[image: from Wang, Q., Cavanagh, P., & Green, M. (1994). Familiarity and pop-out in visual search. Perception & psychophysics, 56(5), 495-500.]

Strangely, In [Treisman's seminal 1980 paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.296.3400&rep=rep1&type=pdf) she also reports a serial slope for color and shape blank trials:
[image: from Treisman, A. M., & Gelade, G. (1980). A feature-integration theory of attention. Cognitive psychology, 12(1), 97-136.]

Is anyone familiar with other examples of a dissociation between target-present and target-absent search slopes, in this direction or in the opposite one (e.g., parallel for blank but serial for target trials)?

Thanks,

-Matan